# How to select multiple values from a single column and store each result in a separate variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have an ASP.NET C# web application tied to a SQL database. I want to query a single column in the database and fetch the result into variables.

My data table looks like this:

```
Collateral_Code | Collateral_Code_Desc | Code_Type
---------------------------------------------------
5700            |Comml Bldg - Fam5+/Apt| Collateral
5705            |Comml Bldg - Hot/Mot  | Collateral
5710            |Comml Bldg - Hot/Mot  | Collateral
```

The query that more closely resembles what I'm looking for is:

```sql
SELECT Collateral_Code_Desc 
FROM tblCollateral_Codes 
WHERE Collateral_Code IN ('5700','5705','5710')
```

The result I get is:

```
Collateral_Code_Desc
---------------------
Comml Bldg - Fam5+/Apt
Comml Bldg - Hot/Mot
Comml Bldg - Hot/Mot
```

I'm getting the values I'm asking for, but I don't know how to grab them.
How can i grab each one of these result values so that they can be stored in variables in my web application?

***  UPDATE ***

Ok, I wasn't sure about needing the C# code and variables for this, I thought you would only need the SQL...

The variables I'm using for this application are:

```
string collCode; 
string collCode2; 
string collCode3;
```

I am using the following try block for my query:

```
con.Open();

    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = " Select Collateral_Code_Desc FROM tblCollateral_Codes Where Collateral_Code IN ('" + collCode +"', '" + collCode2 + "','" + collCode3 + "')" ;

        cmd.Connection = con;

        SqlDataReader myReader;
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (!myReader.HasRows)
        {
            lblCollateralCode1.Text = "N/A";
            lblCollLedgerDesc.Text = "Collateral Code not available";
        }
        else
        {
            if (myReader.Read())
            {
                collCodeDesc = myReader.GetString(0);

            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Label lblMessage = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblMessage");
        lblMessage.Text = "Error handling the request.  Please contact support";
        LogEvent(new AppException("Failed to do something", ex));
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

My connection to the datatable is not a problem.  Grabing the multiple values from the single column (Collateral_Code_Desc) is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Please show us the C# code that produces this result.

Comment: You will find infos at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx and then you can ask for more help.

Comment: I would love to help you but I can't figure out what help you need based on the question as it stands.  What variables are you trying to fill from this query?  Why does `Collateral_Code_Desc` more closely resemble what you want but isn't quite right?  If I had these answers I might be able to help you.

Comment: I've toyed with using a pivot table, but that doesn't work either.  I'm not able to grab the values to store in the codebehind variables.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be implementing a [Sql Data Reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
        }
```

EDIT (Based on your edit):
You have

> ```
> if (myReader.Read())
>         {
>             collCodeDesc = myReader.GetString(0);
>
>         }
> ```

Which will only read one value from the data reader and store it into your variable. Make collCodeDesc into a list and do a while loop so that it will read each line that it returns:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    collCodeDesc.Add(myReader.GetString(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using an ORM? Entity framework is the first that comes to my mind: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388249/How-to-configure-and-use-Entity-Framework

EF also allows you to do directly SQL operations very easily when you need performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to connect to the database and fetch the result. Some of them are:

- [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb9s9ks0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ([SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx), SqlReader, and so on).
- O/R Mapper [LINQ2SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- O/R Mapper [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223258%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)(and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef))

For every option you will need a connection string, that basically says to what database and with which user are you connecting your C# code to the database. It looks like this:

```
// for ADO.NET and indirect for LINQ2SQL
var connectionString = @"Server=sql.server;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=SqlOrWindowsUser;Password=password;";
// for Entity Framework
<add name="ModelEntity" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelEntity.csdl|res://*/ModelEntity.ssdl|res://*/ModelEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SomeServer;Initial Catalog=SomeCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Entity;Password=SomePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

You can have a look [here - www.connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/) how to build your connection string and what the meaning of every part of it is.

**Short explanation:**

ADO.NET is *low level* database access, meaning you need to create and maintain everything by yourself (open the connection, create the command, fetch the result, close the connection, and so on). Quoting Wikipedia about [object relational mapping or short O/R Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping):

> Object-relational mapping (ORM, O/RM, and O/R mapping) in computer
>   software is a programming technique for converting data between
>   incompatible type systems in object-oriented programming languages.

Basically you create a representation in your code of the database structures (tables, procedures) and fill the with data from the database in order to use the data in your code as you are accustomed.

**Code examples:**

Using **ADO.NET** to fetch your data:

```
var connectionString = @"Server=sql.server;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=SqlOrWindowsUser;Password=password;";
string queryString = @"SELECT Collateral_Code_Desc 
                        FROM tblCollateral_Codes 
                        WHERE Collateral_Code IN ('5700','5705','5710');";
var result = new List<String>();
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    // connect to the database
    connection.Open();
    // execute the query
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Using **LINQ2SQL** to fetch your data:

```
// assuming you have created a DBML file and added your tblCollateral_Codes table
var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("linq2sqlConnectionString");
using (var db = new CollateralDatabase(connectionString))
{
    // result is a list of strings, holding in this case 'Comml Bldg - Fam5+/Apt' and so on...
    var result = db.Table
                    .Select(tblCollateral_Codes_Entity => tblCollateral_Codes_Entity.Collateral_Code_Desc)
                    .ToList();
}
```

This [MSDN Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shows you how to connect to your database and add tables to your project using the *O/R Designer* in *Visual Studio*.

The **Entity Framework** code for this operation will actually look exactly as **LINQ2SQL**, just instead of a *DBML* file you create a *EDMX* file.

Every option has many advantages and/or disadvantages, but discussing them is beyond the scope if this answer.